# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{   
    List<String> pathlist = null;
    if (Session["UploadedPath"] != null)
    {
        pathlist = (List<String>)Session["UploadedPath"];
    }
    else
    {
        pathlist = new List<string>();
    }
    string filename = e.FileName;
    string path = "~/Documents/" + filename;
    this.AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
    pathlist.Add(path);
    Session["UploadedPath"] = pathlist;
}
```

Im getting an error like this

Unable to cast object of type `System.String` to type `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String].`

How can i save multiple uploaded file into the databse

Comment: what is the value inside `Session["UploadedPath"]`?

Comment: what is the datatype of Session["UploadedPath"]

Comment: Do a full search of your project for the string Session["UploadPath"], I bet that you will find a place where you set it to a string instead of a List

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida data type of `Session["UploadedPath"]` is always `object`. it depends on the value of that particular object.

Comment: @Sachin I think what SaddamAbuGhaida was referring to was the *underlying* type...

Comment: @Sachin i know but what it was before putting it in the session

Comment: datatype is string...i want to save the multiple uploaded file into th e database how can i do it?plz give the solution

Comment: instead of passing of puttinging it list of file in string seperated by commas or somthing else. put them in a list and then the casting will be working fine

Comment: OT when two users upload a file with the same name (document.docx), then the second one will overwrite the first. This may or may not be a problem for you

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your `UploadedPath` variable is a `string`, not a `List<string>` so you can't perform the following cast

```
pathlist = (List<String>)Session["UploadedPath"];
```

You will need to make sure that when you set `UploadedPath` it's *definitely* an instance of `List<string>` and not a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure 'Session["UploadedPath"];' contains a list type value ?. I think it contains a string value.

```
pathlist = (List<String>)Session["UploadedPath"];
```

will returns the above exception.

Please recheck the value your are stored in the "UploadedPath" session and make sure its a List type

Hope the below code will help you. But make sure if you save something in Session["UploadedPath"]; before, make sure it is a List type.

I am not familiar with AjaxFileUpload, if the 'e' contains only single file at a time, the below will works. But if it contains multiple files, you have to loop through it and add each file to the 'pathlist' and then save it to session

```
protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{   
    List<String> pathlist =  new List<String>();

    if (Session["UploadedPath"] != null)
    {
       pathlist = (List<String>)Session["UploadedPath"];
    }

    string filename = e.FileName;
    string path = "~/Documents/" + filename;
    this.AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
    pathlist.Add(path);
    Session["UploadedPath"] = pathlist;
}
```